# Sort a 2D array by the second value

Tags: javascript

I have an array and I want to sort by the number field not the name.

```
var showIt = [
  ["nuCycleDate",19561100],
  ["ndCycleDate",19460700],
  ["neCycleDate",0],
  ["nlCycleDate",0]
];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can provide `sort` with a comparison function.

```
showIt.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a[1] - b[1];
});
```

`a` and `b` are items from your array. `sort` expects a return value that is greater than zero, equal to zero, or less than zero. The first indicates `a` comes before `b`, zero means they are equal, and the last option means `b` first.

Answer (score 1):

[This site](http://www.breakingpar.com/bkp/home.nsf/0/87256B280015193F87256C8D00514FA4) advises against using the arguments without assigning to temporary variables. Try this instead:

```
showIt.sort(function(a, b) {
    var x = a[1];
    var y = b[1];
    return x - y;
});
```

Comment: That site seems to be talking about reusing the sort callback parameter names within the function. There is no reason not to use `a[1] - b[1]` here.

Answer (score -1):

```
        var temp;
        var newarr= [showIt[0][1],showIt[1][1],showIt[2][1],showIt[3][1]];
        //document.write(newarr);
        for(i=0;i<showIt.length;i++){
            for(j=i+1;j<=showIt.length;j++){
            if(newarr[i] > newarr[j]){
                temp = showIt[i];
                showIt[i]=showIt[j];
                showIt[j]=temp;
            }
        }
        }
        document.write(showIt);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).