# javascript sort 2d arrays and remove some elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

i have created an  array in JS

```
var myArray=[
 [el1,pos1,width1,active1],
 [el2,pos2,width2,active2],
 [el3,pos4,width3,active3],
 [el4,pos1,width4,active4]
];
```

how can i remove elements with active(i)=0?
then i need to sort it by pos(i) ascending
can you give me some samples/solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort a 2D array by the second value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3524827/sort-a-2d-array-by-the-second-value) and [a lot of others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+sort+multidimensional+array). Regarding deletion: The easiest way is do loop over the data and add those values to  a new array that you want to keep.

Comment: but how can i remove subArray where active(i) == 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said, [there are a lot of questions that already cover the sorting issue](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript%20sort%20multidimensional%20array). Have a look at them.

Regarding deletion:

You can iterate over the array and only add the values you want to keep to a new array:

```
var filtered = [];

for(var i = 0, l = myArray.length; i < l; i++) {
    if(myArray[i][3] !== 0) {
        filtered.push(myArray[i]);
    }
}
```

If you want to change the array **in-place**, you can use [**`.splice()`**<sup>[docs]</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

```
for(var i = myArray.length; i--; ) {
    if(myArray[i][3] === 0) {
        myArray.splice(i, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: @gerpaick: You should also accept the answer that helped you the most by clicking the tick outline next do it. You already asked a couple of questions but never accepted an answer...