# Javascript multidimentional array sorting by numerical order

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, sorting

I have a two dimensional array that I need to sort numerically. Here is a sample of the array:

```
   [0]    [1]
    3     320
    55B   250
    26    100
    55A   260
    56    310
    89    420
```

I need to order numerically by the [0] values. The values are stored as strings. I have figured how to sort arrays alphabetically and numerically but I can't figure out how to order this array because of the occasional A and B.

Comment: Do I understand it right, the array is like this: [ [3, 320], ["55B", 250], 26, 100] ] and not [ [3, "55B", 26], [320, 250, 100] ] ?

Comment: Could you maybe describe more specifically how you want the values sorted?  It all seems a little arbitrary right now.  What are the constraints?  In other words, will letters ALWAYS occur in the third position from the left?  Stuff like that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort a 2D array by the second value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3524827/sort-a-2d-array-by-the-second-value)

Comment: As I understand, he know how to sort, but he dont know how to sort numbers with 'A' and 'B' at the end...

Comment: @AdamJurczyk that's basically it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parseInt method will ignore any string characters after the number, removing the A's and B's.

```
arr.sort(function(rowA, rowB){
    var a = parseInt(rowA[0], 10);
    var b = parseInt(rowB[0], 10);

    if (a > b)
        return 1;
    else if (a < b)
        return -1;
    return 0;
});
```

Comment: `arr.sort(function (a, b) { return parseInt(a[0], 10) - parseInt(b[0], 10); });`

Answer (score 0):

Just for note - if this *A* and *B* has nothing to do with sort, than go with `parseInt` as Zack posted.

But if it should be used in sort, you can go with something like this:

```
arr.sort(function(l,r){
  var vl = l[0].split(/(\d+)(\D*)/),
      vr = r[0].split(/(\d+)(\D*)/);

  vl[1] = parseInt(vl[1]);
  vr[1] = parseInt(vr[1]);

  if(vl[1] < vr[1]){
    return -1;
  }else if(vl[1] === vr[1]){
      if(vl[2] < vr[2]) return -1;
      else if(vl[2] === vr[2]) return 0;
      else return 1;
  }else{
      return 1;
  }
});
```