# Order multiple arrays of numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have an array containing multiple arrays of numbers and I want to simply sort them.

For example:

```
my_parent_array = [ [2, 6, 31],
                    [2, 3, 25],
                    [2, 6, 17, 2] ];
```

They are all positive integers and each sub-array could have many values.

I need to sort/order `my_parent_array` to be in order.

So in the above example, it should result like this:

```
my_parent_array = [ [2, 3, 25],
                    [2, 6, 17, 2],
                    [2, 6, 31] ];
```

How can I do this?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

This array contains *numbers only* (and no strings or letters).
I need it to order the sub-arrays first by the first values, then second, etc.
It is similar to sorting it alphabetically, but this is with arrays of numbers not strings of letters.

I assumed that `.sort()` would not do the trick since I am dealing with subarrays.
As @amadan pointed out, a simple `.sort()` would not work, since if I used the standard `.sort()`, a `10` would, by default, come before a `2`.

So is there a sort modifier to do this, or do I need to make my own sorting algorithm?

Thanks.

Comment: [Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), what have you tried?

Comment: It actually is as easy as `my_parent_array.sort()` -> http://jsfiddle.net/6vg5b6ky/

Comment: @adeneo: No, in this specific case it is, but not usually. Try this: `a = [[2], [1], [10]]; a.sort()` - it gives `[[1], [10], [2]]`, since numbers are compared lexicographically. OP's example just doesn't have the case where it matters.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript multidimentional array sorting by numerical order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8070452/javascript-multidimentional-array-sorting-by-numerical-order)

Comment: @Mathemats: Not a general solution, as it only sorts on the first element.

Comment: @Mathemats: No. I am dealing with numbers only and want a way to sort these sub-arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid the problem I posted in the comments (sort being lexicographic by default), introduce your own comparator function:

```
my_parent_array.sort(function(a, b) {
  var len = Math.min(a.length, b.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (a[i] < b[i]) return -1;
    if (a[i] > b[i]) return 1;
  }
  return a.length - b.length;
});
```

EDIT: I keep thinking of corner cases...
EDIT: I think that the corner cases should be solved now.

Comment: What are "corner cases"?

Comment: Failing examples; hopefully none remain, but the edit history would show a number of rewriting and debugging iterations. I probably should have edited that's sentence out when I finally settled on the final version, but I forgot (and now that there's comments referring to it, I probably shouldn't).